# How does "kwargs" is passed to a variable implicitly?

Tags: python, torch, keyword-argument

A simple code from pytorch tutorial, which is used to load the data
'''
tr_data = datasets.FashionMNIST(root="data", train=True, download=True, transform=ToTensor())
'''

[image]

However, when debug into the code as shown above. It use the "new" method without passing the "kwds". It seems the param "transform=ToTensor()" is never used, which in the result is not true. So I am wondering how the code processes the parameter, where-else is the kwds is read into a variable.

Comment: Please *do not post images of code*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's checking to see if the superclass's `__new__` method is the same as `object`'s. This can happen two ways: the superclass is `object`, or the superclass hasn't overridden `__new__` and neither have any of *its* superclasses back to `object`.

`object` doesn't take any arguments in its constructor, so it doesn't pass them if that's the case. Since `object` doesn't take any arguments, it also doesn't need any, so the superclass call creates the object correctly.

After `__new__` is called, `__init__` is called. That is what actually initializes the object (as opposed to creating it). It needs to do something with the arguments, and likely does.

Comment: Yes, after debugging, it was followed by a "init" method which uses the parameters